# Different width when loading same image with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using the following code to convert dp to pixels :

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(float dp){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return Math.round(px);
}
```

and I want to display an image in an ImageView with width of `160dp`.

I first tried using just the android framework to display the image and then I gave a try also to `Picasso` library.

To my amusement I get a visual different result and I don't know how to explain it. So I made a demo app to test it and here is the code and the result in my screen :

```
    int width = ImageHelper.convertDpToPixel(160);
    int height = ImageHelper.convertDpToPixel(100);

    ivNative = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_native);
    ivPicasso = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_picasso);

    ivNative.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

    ivNative.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    ivNative.getLayoutParams().height = height;

    ivNative.requestLayout();

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .resize(width, height)
            .into(ivPicasso);
```

Shouldn't the result be the same? Cause obviously one is much wider than the other.

[image]

XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="test.checkpicasso.MainActivity">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_native"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_picasso" android:layout_below="@+id/iv_native"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ImageView by default tries to maintain aspect ratio whereas Picasso resize does not.

Comment: so its a matter of scale type and not problem with the width ?

Comment: Correct - both image views are the same width - just the bitmap within the first one is not stretched to fill that width, in order to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: @KenWolf indeed! I just tried setting scale type to fitXY and they are the same! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ImageView` by default will attempt to preserve the aspect ratio of the content (not squash it) whereas Picasso's `resize` without specifying a scale type will not. So your two methods are not doing exactly the same thing.

To achieve the same result change your Picasso call to:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .resize(width, height) 
    .centerInside()
    .into(ivPicasso);
```

Alternatively, change your `ImageView` xml to:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_native"
  android:layout_margin="8dp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```